# Passing function to map or starmap in multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

i've been trying to test this simple piece of code on my machine on Jupyter and the cell just runs indefinitely without outputing anything. Is there some kind of bug or something? I use the exact same piece of code for a pandas process with `pool.map` and everything just works fine, but can't figure out what is happening here.

```
import multiprocessing as mp 
pool1 = mp.Pool(processes = 3)

def sumP(a, b):
    return (a * b) / (a - b + 1)

f1, f2, f3 = 24, 31, 45
new_rows2 = pool1.starmap(sumP, [(f1, f2), (f2, f3), (f1, f3)]) 
print(new_rows2)
```

And the cell just keeps running. Doesn't matter if i use `pool1.map` or `pool1.starmap`.
Do you guys suggest any other way of parallelizing this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the worker processes attempt to import `sumP`, which also creates another 3 processes, ad-infinitum.

You'll need to put a guard around the multiprocess creation so that workers don't spawn indefinitely:

```
import multiprocessing as mp 

def sumP(a, b):
    return (a * b) / (a - b + 1)

f1, f2, f3 = 24, 31, 45

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool1 = mp.Pool(processes=3)
    new_rows2 = pool1.starmap(sumP, [(f1, f2), (f2, f3), (f1, f3)]) 
    print(new_rows2)
```

Look for "*Safe importing of main module*" under the [multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods) for more info. You should not create a Pool during importing of the main module.

Comment: Thank you!! It ran fast on the terminal, but still going on an infinite loop on jupyter, besides, how could I measure the time difference between calculating it in parallel versus normal?